# Function to catch any STDERR data

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection, tee

I'm trying to create a function that basically redirects any STDERR to STDOUT.
I'm familiar with redirection when it comes to executing commands, such as:

```
$ echo "all to out" >&2
all to out
$ echo "all to err" >&2
all to err
$ echo "err to out" 2>&1
err to out
$ echo "out to err" 1>&2
out to err
```

But what I'm trying to do, is write a function that can be used to redirect all data that the previous command sent to stderr. Something like this:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nquux" 1>&2 | COMMAND_HERE | grep bar
bar
```

I plan to have this in a function, but it should be just as easy to use the source of the function (that works) via the command line directly.

Here's a few things I've tried, none of which work:

```
$ function 2to1 { exec 2>&1; }
$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nquux" 1>&2 | 2to1 | grep bar
foo
bar
baz
quux
$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nquux" 1>&2 | tee >(cat 2>&1) | grep bar
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

If the `2to` function or the `tee` command worked like I wanted it to, then the output would only be **bar**.

A couple articles/threads i've found somewhat imply that unless I mess with redirection **before** the command gets executed, I wont be able to see `stderr` **after** the command is executed (meaning the command the data is being piped to)

Any input would be appreciated -- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with an ordinary pipe, since only `stdout` is redirected to the pipe.

You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution), specifying that you want `stderr` to be redirected to the process with `2>(...)`.

```
echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nquux" 2>(2to1 | grep bar) 1>&2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in a pipeline. `2to1` needs to be called in sequence with `echo`, the same as if you were calling `exec` directly. You don't pipe to `exec`, you call it first.

```
$ 2to1() { exec 2>&1; }
$ { 2to1; echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz\nquux" 1>&2; } | grep bar
bar
```